# Survey Monkey API: How to add email body as configured in surveymonkey UI?

Tags: email, surveymonkey

I have configured my email collector to display the body in french and I sent survey invite through Survey Monkey. It worked well. Default template is used if this is not specified String in Survey Monkey API. Is there a way to get already configured email collector setup message to be sent? I want the emails to be in the language I had chosen in SM UI

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create a new message based on a template right now is to [copy a previous message](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages).

To do this, you'll want to include the collector/message to use as a template when creating a new message like this:

```
POST /v3/collectors/{collector_id}/messages
{
    "from_collector_id": "<collector_to_use_as_template>",
    "from_message_id": "<message_to_use_as_template>"
}
```

Note that the message ID in the body needs to belong to the collector ID in the body.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to get the message id from Survey Monkey UI?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can just do `GET /v3/collectors/{collector_id}/messages` to fetch a list of your messages for that collector and `GET /v3/collectors/{collector_id}/messages/{message_id}` to get details about any message from that list.

Comment: Is there a way to set the template as default message body when the field is left blank in the API?